# public boolean OnCreateOptionMenu in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I am trying  to implement [this library](https://github.com/Yalantis/Context-Menu.Android/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/yalantis/contextmenu/lib/ContextMenuDialogFragment.java) with fragment. To complete this implementation I must override this menthod

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

But when I try to override this method it gives error "Method does not override method from its superclass".

I have also searched over here for this but nothing worked for me. Please help.

My Code is as follows

```
public class Fragment_Dashboard_Trains extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,OnMenuItemClickListener {@Override
public void onMenuItemClick(View clickedView, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

I am working with support.v4.app.fragment

Comment: Post your fragment code.

Comment: What class are you extending and what are your related imports?

Answer (score 0):

Add  `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in onCreate Method

Like :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Comment: fragment does not have onCreateOptionsMenu(menu menu) method, either this conatins onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) method, so please use this

Comment: yes I have noted that fragment does not have onCreateOptionsMenu(menu menu) method but isn't there any way to implement this library with fragments

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater)) the signature of the method you're trying to override is:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
```

not:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
```

Try to replace your implementation with:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return;
}
```

Comment: now it is showing "attempting to use incompatible return type"

Comment: but library wants boolean return type, if you had a look on the link I have mentioned in the post.

Comment: @swappy I did look at the link and didn't see an implementation of this method at all. Further, the class in your link extends `DialogFragment` which has the signature `public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` as I mentioned in the answer (and posted a link to it as well): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater)

Comment: If you insist on implementing a method with that name and that signature you'll have to remove the `@Override` annotation because the compiler won't find a method with such a signature to override...

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. I just need to implement this method in my base activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    return true;
}
```

and on click menu events can be handled from fragment.

Comment: you can do this in more better way. use sethasmenu() to your fragment oncreate and you can create menu for your each fragment